# How to make overlapping image in PhpOffice\PhpWord?

Tags: phpoffice

I have a document with verious variables in it. Need to put a .png stamp that'll be right on top on them. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using [TemplateProcessor](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html?#setimagevalue) ?